# Cohomology Spectral sequence of a CW complex filtered by its skeletons

Tags: cw-complexes, spectral-sequences

Let $X$ be a CW complex. Suppose, $$\emptyset\subset X^0\subset X^1\subset \cdots \subset X^p\subset \cdots \subset X= \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} X^i,$$
is a filtration of $X$ by its skeletons $X^i$. Now how to get a module filtration of the cochain complex $C^*(X)$ out of this given skeleton filtration, so that we can get the cohomology spectral sequence $(E_r, d_r)$ of the module $C^*(X)$ associated with the (wanted) filtration such that this spectral sequence satisfies:

(i) First quadrant,
(ii) $E_1^{p,q}\cong H^{p+q}(X^p,X^{p-1})$ and
(iii) collapses at $E_2$.

I have tried defining the filtration of $C^*(X)$ as follows:
Let $C_*(X)$ be the singular chain complex of $X$ filtered by
$$0 \subset C_*(X^0)\subset C_*(X^1)\subset \cdots\subset C_*(X^p)\subset \cdots \subset C_*(X).$$
Now define the filtration $F^p$ of $C^*(X)$ by
$$F^p = Ann (C_*(X^{p-1})) = \{f\in C^*(X): f(C_*(X^{p-1}))=0\}.$$
The cohomology spectral sequence obtained from this filtration satisfies (i) above, but I cannot show whether it satisfies (ii) and (iii).

Is the above filtration of $C^*(X)$ correct? If yes how to prove part (ii) and (iii), and if it is not correct then how do we define the filtration of $C^*(X)$.